# Spring Security + OAuth: settings for local JWT validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm building microservices app, secured by Keycloak and want to secure each microservice. It was written here many times, that it's not a good idea to query Auth service (Keycloak - in my case) for every time you want to validate your token. So it's better to validate a signature locally, as soon as your request passes through API-Gateway to the microservices.

So, I want to setup my Spring-app this way.

**Am I right stating that:**

1. `jwt.jwk-set-uri` parameter is responsible for checking JWT keys locally. So when I'm setting up this, open keys will be fetched from Keycloak's endpoint for the future checking of JWT-signature validity offline. Without accessing Keycloak's server per every check.
2. If I set `issuer-uri` without `jwk-set-uri` there will be only on-line JWT-check per every request.

If all of above mentioned is false, please describe the right way in your opinion.
Unfortunately, the [Spring's doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.12.RELEASE/reference/html/oauth2.html) is not so verbose on this, stating that:

> Consequently, Resource Server will not ping the authorization server at startup. We still specify the issuer-uri so that Resource Server still validates the iss claim on incoming JWTs.

The config I'm talking about is here(application.yaml):

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:3000/realms/msapp
          jwk-set-uri: ${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

SecurityConfig

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity()
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyExchange()
                .authenticated().and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer() 
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(keykloakJwtAuthConverter());
        return http.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used alone, `issuer-uri` serves two purposes:

- discover OpenID configuration (which usually stands at `{issuer-uri}/.well-known/openid-configuration`), read the JWKS endpoint URI from it, and then fetch public keys
- setup an issuer validator in the JWT decoder: if the value of the `iss` claim in the token does not match exactly what is configured, an exception is thrown (even trailing slash, if any, is important).

When `jwk-set-uri` is provided, public keys are fetched using it, whatever is configured as `issuer-uri` (which can be omitted, in which case the JWT decoder won't validate the issuer). **But tokens are still validated with a JWT decoder, so you are wrong when thinking that a round-trip to the authorization server is made for every request when you set `jwk-set-uri`.** This round-trip happens when you use access token introspection (instead of JWT decoding) or if you explicitly wire it in the authentication converter or manager (for instance use a REST client to call Keycloak's authorization service).

In my opinion, you should validate issuer, and therefore, provide with `issuer-uri`. In that case, you need to provide a `jwk-set-uri` only if, because of your network configuration, the resource server can't reach the authorization server using what it sets as audience claim (this happens when authorization server is misconfigured and puts a `localhost` URI as audience in a containerized environment). So, in the case of your configuration (where you reuse `issuer-uri` to define `jwk-set-uri`), just remove the `jwk-set-uri`, it will be inferred from OpenID configuration.

P.S.

As already written in another question, you would really save time and efforts reading [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials): your resource server config still has a reference to `/login` (which it should not), CSRF protection is disabled but sessions are still enabled (this is a very bad idea), you are not explicitly returning 401 for unauthorized requests (default is 302 redirect to login which is non-sense for a resource server), there is nothing about CORS configuration which is something you'll probably bump into, and to finish, my guess is you still haven't written a serious `keykloakJwtAuthConverter`.

Comment: Ch4mp, thank you for the detailed explanation! Thank you for pointing me on your tutorials and showing me other errors, I will fix this soon.
Btw, for the sake of truth, I paused Keycloak's container, and ultimately my Resource Server is still able to validate the token. So, definitely, there is no excess additional roundtrip for every request, as you stated above.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation: [resource-server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html):

Resource Server will use this property(`issuer-uri:`) to further self-configure, discover the authorization server’s public keys, and subsequently validate incoming JWTs.

If Resource Server must be able to start up independently from the authorization server, then the `jwk-set-uri` can be supplied.

I think that I give answers to your question for more details, read in your own documentation about resource server provided above there is a good explanation with examples.

Comment: Andrei, thank you for your response. I citated that part of the docs in my question, but ultimately can't grasp it :-(
As it stated: "Resource Server will use this property to ...subsequently validate incoming JWTs". 
So, does it meants that Resource Server will validate incoming JWTs [LOCALLY BY ITSELF], without querying OAuth for every check? So its just queries the keys once for local processing then.
In my opinion, the validation could just be proxied to the Authorization server instead of locally checking.

Comment: i think that`s on oAuth2.0 side for more information you can check here [rfc7662](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662)